# Pagination with Group By in CakePHP 2.0+

Tags: cakephp, group-by, cakephp-2.2, pagination

When paginating results that use GROUP BY in CakePHP, the # of results count is incorrect.  This is a documented item as is (was) to be expected, but according to [this page in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination):

> In CakePHP 2.0, you no longer need to implement paginateCount() when
>   using group clauses. The core find('count') will correctly count the
>   total number of rows.

I'm using CakePHP 2.2.3, yet I still have the problem.  Is there something specific I need to do?  Am I misreading the statement?  Do I still need to use custom paginate() and/or paginateCount methods?

**Clarification of "incorrect count":**  I'm joining table1 w/ table2 - so even though I only have one "table1 item", it retrieves 2 rows... but then I group by to the id of the table1 item, which makes it return only 1 item.  The count, however, shows "2 found", but only displays 1 item.

**Update: (code)**

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
'limit' => (int) 20,
'conditions' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Article.node_type_id' => '5050ede8-3f88-45f4-b58f-1130d9d84497'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'DataText.title LIKE' => '%john%',
            'Article.name LIKE' => '%john%'
        )
    )
),
'order' => array(
    'Article.created' => 'DESC'
),
'fields' => array(),
'joins' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'table' => 'data_texts',
        'alias' => 'DataText',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'DataText.node_id = Article.id'
        )
    )
),
'contain' => array(
    'Slug' => array(
        'order' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'FIELD(Slug.language_id, "c141eafd-567a-4bc5-badd-c5a163c01f46") DESC'
        )
    ),
    'NodeType' => array(
        'ChildNodeType' => array()
    ),
    'DataLocation' => array(
        'conditions' => array()
    ),
    'DataMeta' => array(
        'conditions' => array()
    )
),
'group' => 'Article.id'
```

)

Paginate call itself:

```
$nodes = $this->paginate($model);
```

Comment: Can you post the call with paginate() function that you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in `find("count")` and it returned incorrect count if the query resulted in records for only 1 group. This has been fixed [now](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/33a879ff411928429a5b0188a68eecd9632f87e3). The fix was probably done after 2.2.3 release so just use the `master` branch from github for now and the fix will be available in the next release.

Comment: So I shouldn't need to create a custom count even if I'm doing joins and group bys?

Comment: (it's not mentioned in the 2.3 beta notes:  http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2012/10/28/cakephp_2_3_0-beta_released )

Comment: (I missed the "now" link in your answer - so far so good, I've updated to 2.3 beta, and my count appears to be correct!!  Thank you SOOO very much!)

Comment: It's fixed on the "master" branch itself (i edited the branch name after my initial post), so will be available in the next 2.2 release you don't have to update to 2.3 if you don't want to.